# Is there a word for hating a specific place, such as a town?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

I'm looking for a word that refers either to hating a specific place, or someone who hates a specific place.

If there is a word for hating the place you're in, that would also work.

Comment: For the second, I'd suggest (tongue firmly in cheek) ***homesick***.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is **topophobia** from Greek "topos" (place) and "phobos" (fear).

> **topophobia** *noun*
>
> > a fear of a certain place or location
> >
> > > *His topophobia of his hometown creeped up on him. She has been quite topophobic of Bulawayo lately.*

See it a [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/topophobia).

Or if you specifically want to refer to a home or houses, **oikophobia** from Greek "oikos" (home), or **domatophobia** from Greek "domos" (house). See it a [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/oikophobia).

But since you are saying that the place you are in may also work, then I suggest the simplest solution of **claustrophobia** from Latin "claudere" (to close), which is though being a Greek-Latin hybrid is very known and widely used.

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/claustrophobia):

> **2** : a feeling of discomfort or discontent caused by being in a limiting or restrictive situation or environment
>
> > *the claustrophobia of small-town life*

Also [this list](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/phobias-list) can help.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Based on *misanthrope* and *misogyny*, one could use **misotope/misostopy** or **misotopist/misotopy**, from Greek *topos* "place" and Greek *miseô* "to hate". Graeco-Latin hybrids are generally not preferred, such as **misolocist*.

Comment: Is this actually exist as a word, or you have just coined it? Sounds witty, but it should be mentioned so, I believe.

Comment: @Cerberus That fails, not because it is wrong, but because whoever reads the newly created word has no way of looking up what **-otope** means. I've no objection to newly coined words, per se. I just need it to be possible for the audience to figure them out.

Comment: You're almost better off going with a more English word like **placehate** 
 / **placehater** .